# Should Video.js work in IE8 without Flash plugin?

Tags: flash, video, video.js

The home page for Video.js states the following (emphasis mine):

> Whether a user has the latest version of a browser, or something ancient like Internet Explorer 6, they'll get a similar experience with Video.js **which uses a super-lightweight Flash player for browsers that don't support HTML5 video.**

That says to me that if I have an instance of IE8 without the Flash plugin installed, this "super-lightweight Flash player" should display the video. However, that doesn't appear to be the case; when I go to http://videojs.com, I just see a black box instead of the video.

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of Video.js's embedded Flash player? Or is something else going on?

**UPDATE**: I've added a screenshot, and I get the following unhelpful JavaScript error:

> Message: m`I0_1363975786212

[image]

Comment: For me in IE8 (without flash plugin), I see the video struck. It's not playing. I have to literally drag it to see the video (like dragging it frame by frame)

Comment: Weird, I don't get anything but a black box.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> That says to me that if I have an instance of IE8 without the Flash
>   plugin installed, this "super-lightweight Flash player" should display
>   the video.

I think you misinterpret that statement, and that the wording they use there is not so good. I believe "super-lightweight Flash player" should be read kind of as "super-lightweight video player implemented in Flash, requiring Flash Player plugin".

In other words, the "super-lightweight Flash player" they mention is not a replacement for the entire Adobe Flash Player plugin. It is a video player implemented in Flash, a swf file. The idea is that when HTML5 video is not supported, Flash will be used instead, if the Flash Player plugin is installed.

So to the question "Should Video.js work in IE8 without Flash plugin?", the answer would be no.